# Spring Boot Hibernate Postgres starts up with errors

Tags: java, spring, postgresql, hibernate, jpa

I got a simple Spring Boot application with JPA and Hibernate as a provider. I wanted to test my app against postgres from H2 and every time I start the app for the first time on an empty schema I got errors like that

```
Caused by: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: relation "<table-name>" does not exist
```

but the tables all get created and the app works normal. On next start of the app on the existing schema. Everything seems fine. I have tried

```
<prop key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">create</prop>
and
<prop key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">create-drop</prop>
```

and no different result. 
Does anybody has an idea how I could get a clean boot.

Comment: Do you have tables that reference other tables from different schemas?

Comment: No. They are all in the public schema